# can a router detect client device without initiating something from the devices

Tags: networking, router

can a router detect other WiFi clients (such as smartphones PDA, etc...), from his side, without doing any router search at the device?

the operational scenario is: plurality of WiFi devices, and one router. the devices are not actively trying to connect to a router. the router needs to perform some sort of scan and provide a list of WiFi devices around it - but without creating a network with them.

forgive me if I am not using the proper technical terms.

we are a start-up company with a novel RF technology, and we need to understand how to apply it to the WiFi world.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, no, a wireless router does not "scan" for devices: it (usually) broadcasts it's SSID for other devices to be able to connect to it's wireless access point/network.

There's likely some high-end radio frequency scanning equipment out there that can detect the presence of non-broadcasting wi-fi devices (and maybe get a MAC address), but I can't comment much further on that as I have no experience with wi-fi at that level.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, perhaps you can describe the ideal scenario for your product and we can help you determine what will work, what won't, etc.

Comment: sorry - thanks. a possible scenario is plurality of wi-fi devices, such as phones. we want to "see" how many devices are within the communication range of the router. we control the router, not the deivces. i nkow that there are some very basic levels of the "handshake' that might be applicable. thanks again or the answer

Comment: if the devices are not connected to a wlan, but are "active" they will normally search for a wlan via probe requests, those can be captured and are providing a MAC you might be able to use. These days the hardware itself is cheapish (a few € for an OK usb dongle)